# Align adapter row elements

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to align row elements in my listview.
I have a layout row xml file that hold this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TV_list_from_db_p_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/BTN_addOne_from_db"
            android:layout_width="33dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/button"
            android:onClick="addOneToQuantity"
            android:text="+" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/TV_Quantity_from_db"
            android:layout_width="44dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp" >
        </EditText>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/BTN_subOne_from_db"
            android:layout_width="33dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/button"
            android:onClick="subOneToQuantity"
            android:text="-" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/CHK__list_from_db"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
  />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image: This code gives me this:]
                I want the elements
to be aligned, now its aligned by the length of the text view

like this:
|TextView|Number Picker| CheckBox|
|TextView|Number Picker| CheckBox|
|TextView|Number Picker| CheckBox|

Any ideas?

Comment: use a table layout ? (or, if you really need the listview, use fixed size views for all after the label, and width 0 weight 1 for the label)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using LinearLayout, you can give the inner LinearLayout and the CheckBox both `layout_width="wrap_content"` and give the TextView `layout_width="0dp"` and `layout_weight="1"`

Answer (score 0):

Use a relative layout and put in these order:

```
Check box - align parent right - width="30dp"
Button1 - to left of check box - width="33dp"
Edit Text - to left of Button1 - width="44dp"
Button2 - to left of Edit Text - width="33dp"
TextView - align parent left and to left of Button2 - width wrap_content
```